# SQL - Select info from table where data has max count of rev

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to select info from my table where data have max rev number but failed.
[image]

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  Name,
  REV
FROM Dms_sub
WHERE REV = (SELECT MAX(cast(REV as INT)) FROM Dms_sub GROUP BY Name)
```

Getting error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can use row_number() to get the rank and if you order DESC and get RANK = 1 that should give you the record with the highest REV

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 
ID,
  Name,
  REV,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY REV DESC) AS RANK
FROM Dms_sub) i
WHERE RANK = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
select id, NAME, max(rev)
from Dms_sub
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve using IN operator like below.

```
SELECT 
ID,
  Name,
  REV
FROM Dms_sub
WHERE REV IN (SELECT MAX(cast(REV as INT)) FROM Dms_sub GROUP BY Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can condition it by it's max rev using sub query

```
(SELECT MAX(cast(REV as INT)) FROM Dms_sub GROUP BY Name)
```

this condition is not right because it returns a multiple row because you haven't include the name condition in your sub query which is this

```
WHERE  NAME = DmsSub.NAME
```

this is the right way to condition it to it's max rev

```
SELECT id, 
       NAME, 
       rev 
FROM   Dms_sub AS DmsSub 
WHERE  rev = (SELECT Max(rev) 
              FROM   Dms_sub 
              WHERE  NAME = DmsSub.NAME)
```